# Copy the information of array into a pointers array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, copy

```
  unsigned char brillo[3], *brilloGrup[9], brillZero[3]={0,0,0};

  brilloGrup[1][0] = (!LeeValor(i-1, j-1,  brillo))?  brillZero : brillo ;
  brilloGrup[2][0] = (!LeeValor(i-1, j,    brillo))?  brillZero : brillo ;
  brilloGrup[3][0] = (!LeeValor(i-1, j+1,  brillo))?  brillZero : *brillo ;
  brilloGrup[4][0] = (!LeeValor(i,   j+1,  brillo))?  brillZero : *brillo ;
  brilloGrup[5][0] = (!LeeValor(i+1, j+1,  brillo))?  brillZero : *brillo;
  brilloGrup[6][0] = (!LeeValor(i+1, j,    brillo))?  brillZero : *brillo ;
  brilloGrup[7][0] = (!LeeValor(i+1, j-1,  brillo))?  brillZero : *brillo;
  brilloGrup[8][0] = (!LeeValor(i,   j-1,  brillo))?  brillZero : *brillo;
```

In this form now I'm copying the address of the brillo and I need to copy the information. Do you know how I can copy?

Answer (score 0):

To copy data between `char` arrays, use `strncpy` or `memcpy` (depending on whether the arrays are NUL-terminated).

Answer (score 0):

`brilloGroup` is just an array of 9 pointers to `unsigned char`, so you can't copy data without also including some code to allocate room for that data.

Comment: Hi, my idea is copy the information from the array. I know that i use an array of pointers but I try to do this code for make it more clean and easy, becouse if I use strcmpy  or similar I will need  use a lot of "if" and the code look like very dirty.